# Use Python regular expression to extract special strings

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Given strings like:

```
str = '12-1 abcd fadf adfad'
```

I want to get `12-1`. How can you do it in python?

I'm using the following code, but does not work.

```
m = re.search('.*(\number+-\number+).*', str)
if m:
    found = m.group(0)
    print found
```

Comment: You should have a look over this page so you're better with using regular expressions in python in the future: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Aside: even though this is simply an example, rebinding built-in names like `str` is a bad habit to get into..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import re
str = '12-1 abcd fadf adfad'
m   = re.search('(\d+-\d+)', str)
if m:
    found = m.group(0)
    print found
```